# Magento 2 : how to override pagination in admin panel?

Tags: magento2, admin, pagination

I have created a tab in admin panel and I'm showing my custom grid in that tab.
magento2 by default shows 20 records in a grid but I want to show more than 20 records by default.

i have found this core file:

> vendor\magento\module-backend\Block\Widget\Grid.php

```
protected $_defaultLimit = 20;
```

I want to override this file so I have created the custom module.

**File1:** Di.xml

```
<type name = " Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid " >

    <plugin name="Test_fullActionNameAlert_backend_grid" type="Test\FullActionNameAlert\Block\Widget\Grid" sortOrder="10" />

 </type>
```

**File2**: Grid.php

```
namespace Test\FullActionNameAlert\Block\Widget;

/*use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid as WidgetGrid;*/

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid
{

    protected $_defaultLimit = 50;
}
```

I have already run all necessary commands, but still, this script isn't working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use magento's default function `$this->setDefaultLimit($yourLimit)` in where you define grid id, default sort order as below function.

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setId('vendor_example_mygrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('id');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setDefaultLimit(100); // your default limit
}
```